# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows 7 32-bit

Tags: java, windows-7, 32-bit

I tried to run a programm that use java (BEAST) but all time give me this error in a text file.

I'm running it in a Toshiba laptop, and Windows 7 32-bit. Any idea on how i can solve the problem?

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>       #
>       #  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x46d9b6c0, pid=5536, tid=5600
>       #
>       # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_45-b15) (build 1.8.0_45-b15)
>       # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.45-b02 mixed mode windows-x86 )
>       # Problematic frame:
>       # C  [hmsbeagle-cpu-sse32-21.DLL+0xb6c0]
>       #
>       # Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
>       #
>       # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>       #   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
>       # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
>       # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
>       #

Comment: HaveNoDisplayName, do you have an idea of what I could do? Or where can I find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

When I hit a breakpoint in String.Class 461 row。I run is ok 。Debug will appear

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000064ab4759, pid=11536, tid=13640
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_79-b15) (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.79-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x54759]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client 
  versions of Windows
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# E:\ideaWorkspace\git\fee_manage\hs_err_pid11536.log
```